# Repeat name by using counter

Tags: php, html, counter

```
echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from" class="datepicker"/>'."</td>";
```

How can I repeat name attribute using counter & how to store it using `$_POST[]`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: what is the excepted result?

Comment: I have to save date several times, so i have to use different name for different input tag. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `[]` in order to repeat names

```
echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from[]" class="datepicker"/>'."</td>";
echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from[]" class="datepicker"/>'."</td>";
echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from[]" class="datepicker"/>'."</td>";
```

Then result of $_POST includes an array containing a key named `date_from` with all the values you have inserted before

Comment: It gives error Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<Number_of_times_to_repeat;$i++)
{
echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from_$i" class="datepicker"/>'."</td>";
}
```

this will name each  as date_from_0,date_from_1.... and so on. That can be used in your POST.

Comment: I used it but it didnt work. $_POST['date_from_$I'], is this right?

Comment: you cannot use $i outside the loop. Are you posting the data or are you grabbing the data ? if you are grabbing the data its.    $some_data_0=$_POST['date_from_0']; $some_data_1=$_POST['date_from_1']; ..... and so on

Comment: This is my code             while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){    
     echo "<tr><td>".$row['Driver_name']
           ."<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"driver_name[]\" value=\"".$row['Driver_name']."\"/></td>";
     $sel1='select d_status from status';
     $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel1);
     echo "<td><select name=\"status[]\">";
     while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
           echo "<option value=\"".$row1['d_status']."\">".$row1['d_status']."</option>";
     }
     echo "</select></td>";
     echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from[]" class="datepicker"/>'."</td>";

Comment: sudhi, can u help me?

Comment: while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{ 
 echo "<tr><td>".$row['Driver_name'] ."<input type='hidden' name='" . $row['driver_name'] . " value='".$row['Driver_name']."'/></td>"; 
 $sel1='select d_status from status'; 
 $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel1); 
 echo "<td><select name='status'>"; 
 while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1))
 { 
  echo "<option value=\'".$row1['d_status']."'>" . $row1['d_status'] . "</option>"; 
 } 
 echo "</select></td>";
 for($i=0;$i<$Number_of_times_to_repeat;$i++)
 {
 echo "<td>".'<input type="text" name="date_from_' . $i . '" class="datepicker"/>'."</td>";
 }
}

Comment: This for loop is not working here. Is it right  $_POST['date_from_.$i.']?